# Changing content of Fragment (Fragment tab) dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created a tabbed window using fragments, I have three tabs now in one of the tabs I have a requirement of changing the contents without changing the tab, I searched over and came up with the following:

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, container, false);


        Button b = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        b.setOnClickListener(on);

        return rootView;



    }
    private View.OnClickListener on = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();  
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager  
                    .beginTransaction();  
            Fragment3 fragment3 = new Fragment3();  
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.layout.fragmenttab1, fragment3);  
            fragmentTransaction.commit();  

        }
    };




}
```

This is my Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Tab Variable
    ActionBar.Tab Tab1, Tab2, Tab3;
    Fragment fragmentTab1 = new FragmentTab1();
    Fragment fragmentTab2 = new FragmentTab2();
    Fragment fragmentTab3 = new FragmentTab3();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Hide Actionbar Icon
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        // Hide Actionbar Title
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        // Create Actionbar Tabs
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set Tab Icon and Titles
        Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.tab1);
        Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Reminders");
        //Tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.tab1);
        Tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Notifications");
        //Tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.tab1);
        Tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Contacts");

        // Set Tab Listeners
        Tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab1));
        Tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));
        Tab3.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab3));

        // Add tabs to actionbar
        actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(Tab2);
        actionBar.addTab(Tab3);
    }
}
```

And here is the fragment class:

```
public class Fragment3 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab3, container, false);
        return rootView;



    }
}
```

However when I run this program, I get a strange error:

```
12-03 17:51:20.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 17:51:20.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f030002 for fragment Fragment3{4155bdb8 #1 id=0x7f030002}
12-03 17:51:20.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:789)
12-03 17:51:20.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:998)
12-03 17:51:20.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
12-03 17:51:20.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1330)
12-03 17:51:20.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:417)
12-03 17:51:20.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-03 17:51:20.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-03 17:51:20.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-03 17:51:20.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-03 17:51:20.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 17:51:20.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-03 17:51:20.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-03 17:51:20.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-03 17:51:20.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any pointers where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Check out my post here. It contains all you need

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120510/dynamically-changing-the-fragments-inside-a-fragment-tab-host/19859871#19859871>

Comment: I am using a fragment tab, not the good old tab host.

Comment: Cube Stuffs has been done using FragmentTabHost. Kindly check that out

Comment: chek out my post over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120510/dynamically-changing-the-fragments-inside-a-fragment-tab-host/19859871#19859871

Comment: Hey mate, it works, I had to replace the R.layout with R.id. Craft an answer and I will accept it, now the next task is to add it to back stack :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code not finding any problem.

Layouts having the problem.please check both fragment layouts and the main activity layout.