# How to create tab view in fragment android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs

I have created a navigation drawer from androidhive which in using Fragments. Now I want to create a 3 tabs inside fragment, I have tried every thing but not able to create the tabs, please guide me to create tabs. I will post my code.

```
public class ViewGuestlist extends Fragment {

    CalendarView calendar;//http://192.168.1.91/music_admin/display_menulist

    public ViewGuestlist(){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);



        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
     public void onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu,android.view.MenuInflater inflater) {
      menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setTitle("Select Date");

      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
     }; 

    /* @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hi..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         Log.v("hi", "hi");
         Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.calendar);
         dialog.setTitle("Select Date");

         calendar = (CalendarView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
         calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view,int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),dayOfMonth +"/"+month+"/"+ year,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

         dialog.show(); 



         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }*/

}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="Communities View"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtLabel"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_communities"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If in addition to `NavigationDrawer` you want to add `Tabs` then have a look at this [example](https://github.com/Balaji-K13/Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip)

Comment: Check out my post over here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120510/dynamically-changing-the-fragments-inside-a-fragment-tab-host/19859871#19859871>