# The fragment which is got from backstack, call onCreateView() again

Tags: android, fragment, back-stack

Please help me resolve my issue.

I have `MainActivity` with a framelayout. I want to replace some fragments into  the framelayout. Now I am encounering an issues, it's:

1) I created and put fragment A to framelayout. Fragment A called `onCreateView`...etc.

2) Then I created and put fragment B to layout... Fragment A was put on backstack and it called `onPause()` (not called `onDeattach()`, `onDestroy`...)

3) I pressed back button. Fragment A was got from backstack, but it called `onCreateView()` again. This action make my app has some another issues.

So my question is how to store fragment A in backstack and it don't recreate view.

This's the method that was used to change fragment:

```
public static void setContent(FragmentManager managerFragment, Fragment detailFragment) {
    if (managerFragment != null) {
        if(lastFragment==null && detailFragment instanceof HomeVer3Fragment ||
                (lastFragment!=null && detailFragment instanceof HomeVer3Fragment && lastFragment instanceof HomeVer3Fragment)){
            return;
        }
        String tag=detailFragment.getClass().getName();
        managerFragment.popBackStackImmediate(tag, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        FragmentTransaction ft = managerFragment.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, detailFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(tag);
        ft.commit();
        lastFragment = detailFragment;
    }
}
```

Thank and sorry for my bad question, my english is not well.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle. you need to take a look at fragment lifecycle for point 2 and 3

Answer (score 2):

check out my complete post over here [Dynamically changing the fragments inside a fragment tab host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120510/dynamically-changing-the-fragments-inside-a-fragment-tab-host/19859871#19859871)

As far your problem of reloading ( I assume ) you can do some thing like undermentioned:

(1) Initiate a Boolean value say

```
boolean android_hacker = false;
```

(2) Now say U need to fetch data and create some view using list view. Now at this stage set "android_hacker = true;" after you have fetched all data.

(3) Now when U again come back to same fragment say "FragmentA" then check value on OnCreateView as mentioned ..

```
if(android_hacker != true){
        new GoAsyncTask().execute();
        }else{
// Perform stuff U need
}
```

That's it. Hope it helps some one

Comment: I think fragment always call onCreateView after pop it off from backstack

Comment: Yes of course method is called each time as that is flow of fragment. Solution is for same thing only. Give it a try.

Comment: @AndroidHacker Something you can fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60327414/preserve-view-with-data-of-recyclerview-list-in-navcontroller-fragments ?