# FragmentActivity and TabHost - I don't understand anything

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I've seen all the posts of TabHost + FragmentActivity on Google Groups and on StackOverflow and I'm still getting problems.

And I don't understand anything.

I'm following this tutorial for TabHost and FragmentActivity: http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/

I have the following thing:
in a tab I load a `CategoriaFragment.class`, where I load a `ListView` and I set a `ListView.OnItemClickListener` for it. When I click, I call this code:

```
CategoriaFragment fragmentnuevo = new CategoriaFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putBoolean("flagSottoCategorie", true);
b.putSerializable("sottocategorielista", (Serializable)sottocategorielista);
fragmentnuevo.setArguments(b);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.add(R.id.realtabcontent, fragmentnuevo, FragmentTAG); // FragmentTAG is the same tag that the current Fragment
transaction.commit();
```

and yes, I call the same type of Fragment because I need the same recurses but with another `List`(sottocategorielista). This is not the error because I've tried to use another .class and it's the same error.

When I press back button, I get again my first `ListView` but listeners are not available. So I click and nothing happens. I've used `add` and `replace` as well.

Moreover, when I try to change Tab, if `add` is typed, I get several fragments in the same layout, if `remove` is typed, I get only one fragment on onTabChanged, but when I get back to my Fragment, nothing is available. Moreover if I press back button, I get the `java.IllegalStateException` saying

> Fragment is already added: CategoriaFragment

What should I do?
Everything is easier with TabActivity, which is deprecated now and I would like to do everything with Fragments.

This is how my `onTabChanged` works (also available on the resource on the web)

```
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    if (mLastTab != newTab) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (mLastTab != null) {
            if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
            }
        }
        if (newTab != null) {
            if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,
                        newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
            } else {
                ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
            }
        }

        mLastTab = newTab;
        ft.commit();
        this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You can either remove the previous fragment and add the new one or just call fragmentTransaction.replace() and add your new fragment.

Comment: Fallow my post .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120510/dynamically-changing-the-fragments-inside-a-fragment-tab-host/19859871#19859871

Comment: FWIW, here is my book's action bar tabs sample app: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/TabFragmentDemo

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm not using the ActionBar, but a independent TabHost because I want to handle to the bottom

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misread the method signature of your code snippet. Note that bottom tabs violate the Android design guidelines. Beyond that, try `FragmentTabHost` rather than `TabHost`.

Comment: Yeah, I'd love to have the way to use my ActionBar at the bottom of my screen, but I looked for and I got anything :\

Comment: @AndroidHacker the same problems happen.

If I go to my TAB2 where there's my `ListView` is, I switch to TAB3 and go back to TAB2, my `ListView` doesnt have listeners.

Comment: @RafaFirenze you need to perform some check condition ...Fallow my answer for same.

Answer (score 0):

Some time there's problem for listeners in list view or more specifically I say some time our list view loads every time we switch our view in Fragment.

To solve this problem android in itself provides some methods which I believe can be found very easily over stack.

So I am going to put some general way to perform same.

(1) Define boolean value say Boolean `androidHacker = false;`

(2) Now when you populate your list view then set that value to true. i.e when you successfully fetch your value then set same to true .. `androidHacker = true;`

(3) Now every time on `OnCreateView();` method check that value like ..

```
if(androidHacker == true){

// Simply populate your value using Model and Adapter

}else{

//fetch your server data  and inflate same to list view as this is first time your have //entered your fragment class 
}
```

Hope this solves your problem!

For more reference on using FragementTabHost fallow ..[Dynamically changing the fragments inside a fragment tab host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120510/dynamically-changing-the-fragments-inside-a-fragment-tab-host/19859871#19859871)