# FragmentActivity as ActiivtyGroup in tabwidget

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, activitygroup

I have a FragentActivity lets say 'X' in tabhost.Now i want to make it work as activitygroup how can i start another activity 'Y' from this fragmentActivity so that it become part of that tab. The problem is if activity extends ActivityGroup,the getFragmentManager() function becomes undefined and in case of extending with FragmentActivity i cannot start a next activity withan that tabhost.Help me if someone knows the solution.

Comment: use setup() method with a custom LocalActivityManager class object

Comment: @pskink: kindly will u give me some code of this setup method. i could not understand ur suggestion

Answer (score 0):

`ActivityGroup` is deprecated as per [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html).

**Solution:**

I would insist to use `Fragment` and `FragmentManager` to implement same feature in your app.
You may have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19859871/1288725) to achieve the same behavior.

I hope it will be helpful.