# How to use findFragmentByTag inside nested Fragments with TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

Here I've nested TabLayouts inside a `Fragment` which is working so fine for me but not I just want to know how I can switch Tabs of `TabLayouts` when `MainTabFragment` is not in front of app. I searched for a long time and I found it's possible with `findFragmentByTag` but I don't know how I should use it in my case where I have to switch Tabs too. For more I'm writing my code too.

In `MainActivity` I'm switching Tabs when `MainTabFragment` is in front and calling that Fragment when it's not in front like:

```
 Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
            if (currentFragment instanceof MainTabFragment) {  
           //Main Fragment
                MainTabFragment.pager.setCurrentItem(1);
          // Child Fragment of Main Fragment
                TopAdvisoryPagerFragment.pager.setCurrentItem(2);
            } else {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        fragment = new MainTabFragment();
                        changeFragments();                           
                    }
                }, 150);
            }
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

  public void changeFragments() {

    if (fragment != null) {
        mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("pos_next", second_position);
                bundle.putInt("pos_end", third_position);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, "TOP").addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        };        
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }

    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120510/dynamically-changing-the-fragments-inside-a-fragment-tab-host

Comment: Can you please explain it lil more because I've nested Fragments?

Comment: You can make nested fragment tabs with actionbar sherlock [link](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-actionbarsherlock-nested-fragment-tabs-tutorial/)

Comment: No..I have done everything. I just wanted to know lil bit more according of Toolbar ant tabLayout. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong,

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(com.cws.advisorymandi.R.id.frame_container, fragment, "TOP");
```

Tag refer to "TOP", if you have different fragment using the same tag, it would be difficult to switch. You could possibly change the code to

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(com.cws.advisorymandi.R.id.frame_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

In this scenario, the tag will be your fragment class name.

Comment: What you mean? I don't quite get what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok. I have a MainActivity and MainTabFragment inside that. And MainTabFragment also has 3 more child fragments. So I can switch their Tabs also by using `findFragmentByTag`

Comment: Switch fragments when I `MainTabFragment` comes infront of app.

Comment: Do you have a app flow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97925/discussion-between-anshul-tyagi-and-ophitect).