# Where do I get resource id of fragment container?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My app consists of tab layout and each tab has is its own fragment. I have never encountered the need for a "fragment container" until i needed to refresh the current fragment when its parent `AppCompatActivity` clicked the back button.

Here is my Code for When I want to Refresh the Fragment:

```
GlobalFeedTab fragment = (GlobalFeedTab)
    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);


getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .detach(fragment)
    .attach(fragment)
    .commit();
```

**PageAdapter:**

```
      public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int tabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mTabs = tabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            GlobalFeedTab tab1 = new GlobalFeedTab();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            CountryFeedTab tab2 = new CountryFeedTab();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            CountryList tab3 = new CountryList();
            return tab3;
        case 3:
            NotificationsTab tab4 = new NotificationsTab();
            return tab4;
        case 4:
            ProfileTab tab5 = new ProfileTab();
            return tab5;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mTabs;
 }
```

}

**MainActivity:**

```
            public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);




    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.earthicon));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.flagicon));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.listicon));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.notificationsiconi));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.profileicon));
   // tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });



   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know your fragments ID, you can use the method [`FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)), where the tag is a String you either put in your fragment's XML attributes or in the fragment transactions [add or replace calls](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: When I start typing `FragmentManager.` .... `findFragmentByTag()` doesn't pop up @pdegand59

Comment: What is a container and how do I reference it. I just need it to refresh the current Fragment

Comment: the method is not static, you have to do `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag()`

Comment: And if you really want to do it with ids, show the code where you add each fragment for each tab and how do you switch fragment when you switch tab.

Comment: I still don't understand where I get the String

Comment: see last comment, can't help you more without more code

Answer (score 0):

1.
    ((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId();
2.
    Checkout out this answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120510/dynamically-changing-the-fragments-inside-a-fragment-tab-host)